# C# - check if a custom list contains a username and if his password it's correct

Tags: c#

Noob question! Need some help!
So I'm using GoogleSheets API to store user credentials.
I created a custom list with all the data of every user in the GoogleSheet, I need to verify if the data inserted by user matches something within the list.

I managed to check if the username matches, but how to check if the password matches that username?

##The class

```
public class ListadeJogadoresRegistados
        {
            public int id { get; set; }
            public string nome { get; set; }
            public string pwd { get; set; }
            public int hiscore { get; set; }

        }
```

##Building the list

```
private static List<ListadeJogadoresRegistados> GetListaJogadores()
        {
            var request = service.Spreadsheets.Values.Get(SpreadsheetID, range);

            var response = request.Execute();
            var values = response.Values;

            var jogador = new List<ListadeJogadoresRegistados>();

            foreach (var row in values)
            {
                jogador.Add(new ListadeJogadoresRegistados
                {
                    id = Int32.Parse((string)row[0]),
                    nome = (string)row[1],
                    pwd = (string)row[2],
                    hiscore = Int32.Parse((string)row[3])
                });
            }

            return jogador;
        }
```

##Data validation

```
public static bool ValidarLogin(string username, string pwd)
        {
            var jogadores = GetListaJogadores();

            ListadeJogadoresRegistados item = jogadores.Find(item => item.nome == username && item.pwd == pwd);
            if (item != null) // check item isn't null
            {
                
               // it is logged in
                
            }
            return true;
```

Comment: `item => item.nome == username` -> `item => item.nome == username && item.pwd == pwd`, although you should never store user passwords in cleartext

Comment: Do the same for password. Just merge conditions using `&&` in `Find` method. Update your code with the changes if that doesn't work.

Comment: I feel like this shouldn't really be answered because its just such a bad idea to do...

Comment: @Pirate tried that before and didn't work

Comment: @JoaoCoelho Please update your code with that change and explain what went wrong.

Comment: @Pirate updated, it says that the object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen thanks for answer. I know that I shouldn't do that, it's a work for a algorithm class, and the teacher asked me to do something like this

Comment: @Pirate it's working!!! thanks a lot!

Comment: @Pirate I was testing with wrong password, of course it was retrieving null!
Thanks a lot!!